# Decorators as classes

Tags: python, class, python-decorators

Trying to rewrite a decorator as a `Class`  isn't working as expected. My actual decorator is:

```
def check(callback):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            cb_result = callback()
            return result 
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

My approach to class format is

```
class Check(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *call_args, **call_kwargs):
        function = call_args[0]
        return self.__param__call__(function)

    def __param__call__(self, function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            cb_result = callback()
            return result 
        return wrapper
```

I expect to use the decorator as in:

```
@Check(callback=a_function_callback)
def my_function():
    ...
```

What is my mistake while rewriting it as a class, I'm also always trying to keep backwards compatibility (aka Python 2.7 compliance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should accept `callback` as a parameter in your `Check` class' `__init__` method, so that your `wrapper` function can actually reference it as a callback function:

```
class Check(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def __call__(self, func):
        return self.__param__call__(func)

    def __param__call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            cb_result = self.callback()
            return result 
        return wrapper
```